# react-native vertical center TextInput on ios

Tags: react-native, textinput

in react-native when you make a TextInput multiline, the text inside the input is top aligned in IOS and center aligned in Android.
According to the [doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#multiline) we may use 'textAlignVertical' to align top the Text on android
But it don't work on IOS

my question is: How to vertical align center a Text in IOS multiline TextInput

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the property `textAlignVertical` is for [Android only](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#multiline). The common workaround is to put the `TextInput` into the center of a container with a fixed height:

```html
<View style={{height:200, width:200, justifyContent:"center"}}>
   <TextInput 
     multiline={true} 
     numberOfLines={10} 
     style={{textAlign:"center", width:"100%"}} 
     placeholder="Something useful" />
</View>
```

or

```html
<View style={{height:200, width:200, justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center"}}>
   <TextInput 
     multiline={true} 
     numberOfLines={10} 
     placeholder="Something useful" />
</View>
```

will do the trick.